# Carnevil losing DPS of my fetishes?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I just found a Carnevil http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/carnevil

My issue is that I think I'm losing the "dagger" dps of my fetishes. Does anyone know the damage is the same as their daggers when they shoot? My attack speed is really high so they shoot rather fast, but they now lose the Tasker and Theo attack speed (my attack speed bonus is 80% from them) because they only shoot when I do.

Is it recommended to go with Tasker and Theo and keep that attack speed or keep the poison dart shooting fetishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no one uses this helm anymore, so don't use it.

To answer the question, you would, in fact, lose DPS from using this helm in this situation.

But now in the later patches, you're better off using the set [Zuni's for a pet build anyway](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/voodoo-mask/#type=set)